# picturebox doubleclick and click events

Tags: click, picturebox

I have a picturebox and 2 events:

```
picbox.Click += new System.EventHandler(clickpicbox);
picbox.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(picbox_DoubleClick);
```

Now, the click event works just fine but the doubleclick doesn't even get fired!!

What might cause this?

If I remove the Click event then the doublecklick gets fired, so it's weird..

I have nothing in those events by the way, as I'm testing what it may be I did not include any code in the actual functions for each event..

Thanks!

Comment: taking a stab in the dark but from an algorithm design perspective perhaps once a click is recognized it is discarding that event and thus never recognizing a "double click" because it is only catching the clicks and discarding them

Comment: Well, it should be 2 separate events I think..

Comment: @Matimont , I have the same issue. Have you found the answer?

Comment: [Check my answer in this post, It is working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132136/picture-box-double-click-single-click-events/20133472#20133472