# Picture box, Double click & Single click events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I have an strange issue. I have a picture box double click event as well as single click event. The problem is even I double click the control, single click event is raised [If I disable single click event, double click event is working]. [This problem has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305572/picturebox-doubleclick-and-click-events) , but nobody gave a right answer

Comment: you will have to fire the events only when all the clicks are done. may be you could use a timer and then a count to maintain the number of clicks. if it one- fire the single click, if it's 2, fire the double click event

Comment: Something similar to this http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=109865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a derived Picturebox control class

```
class PictureBoxCtrl:System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
{
    // Note that the DoubleClickTime property gets 
    // the maximum number of milliseconds allowed between 
    // mouse clicks for a double-click to be valid.
    int previousClick = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;
    public new event EventHandler DoubleClick;

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        int now = System.Environment.TickCount;
        // A double-click is detected if the the time elapsed
        // since the last click is within DoubleClickTime.
        if (now - previousClick <= SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
        {
            // Raise the DoubleClick event.
            if (DoubleClick != null)
                DoubleClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        // Set previousClick to now so that 
        // subsequent double-clicks can be detected.
        previousClick = now;
        // Allow the base class to raise the regular Click event.
        base.OnClick(e);
    }

    // Event handling code for the DoubleClick event.
    protected new virtual void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DoubleClick != null)
            this.DoubleClick(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then use create objects by using the class

```
            PictureBoxCtrl imageControl = new PictureBoxCtrl();               
            imageControl.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(picture_DoubleClick);
            imageControl.Click += new EventHandler(picture_Click);
```

Then Implement picture_Click and picture_DoubleClick with your requirements

```
void picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Custom Implementation
}

void picture_DoubleClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Custom Implementation
}
```

[Reference for this implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172533.aspx)